# Nano - disable confirm on save?

Tags: linux, nano

I use nano every day and I really hate when it asks every time to "save modified buffer? (yes/no)". How can I disable this?

Comment: in `nano.c` change the `do_exit()` function.

Answer (score 7):

I didn't like setting `tempfile` because then it also doesn't prompt you when you exit with `ctrl+X`. In fact, it will silently save your changes when you exit! And you can't exit without saving!

Instead, I have added this keybinding for `ctrl+S` to my `~/.nanorc`:

```
bind ^S savefile main
```

`savefile` will save the file without prompting you to confirm the filename, like other editors. But if you use `ctrl+X`, it will prompt you if you have changes.

Comment: This solution seems similar to the one with `set tempfile`, but setting tempfile does not work and still prompts with ctrl+o.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the -t flag when starting nano. From the man page:

> -t (--tempfile) Always save changed buffer without prompting. Same as Pico's -t option.

Answer (score 2):

In `~/.nanorc`, for nano version higher 5.0:

```
set saveonexit
```

for version below 5.0:

```
set tempfile
```

Also, its a good idea to add:

```
set backup
set backupdir /home/user/.nano-backups
```

All files will be automatically backed up in this directory, and it is much better then confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [tempfile setting](http://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.0/nano.html).

If you want a *permanent* setting, edit your **~/.nanorc** file (or create it) and add:

```
set tempfile
```

Alternatively, you can start nano with the `-t` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

On RPI `ctrl+s`+`ctrl+x` works naturally